# Different output between xelatex and lualatex with the same font

Tags: xetex, luatex

With the following code, I get the small caps with lualatex but not with xelatex,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=155}]
{Charis SIL}          % sets the document font
\begin{document}
číčí abcd $abcd$ $číčí$

\bfseries\scshape abc ABC \normalfont \\
The german ß compiles to SS when used


\end{document}
```

and the tracking works only with lualatex.
The font is [here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=CharisSIL_download)

Comment: You need to specify `Renderer=ICU` see the linked duplicate question.

Comment: ICU does solve the problem.